# CakePHP: Correct Way to set Request Data after redirect

Tags: forms, cakephp-2.0

I want to set the request data after/on a redirect so the user does not need to fill in a registration form twice, the form is used in several places and needs to return to the referrer.

what is the best way of doing this? I was thinking of setting a session and destroying it again when read.

The method I am working with as follows:

```
// Check Existing User
if ((int) $this->User->checkIfUserExist($this->request->data['User']['username']) > 0) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Username Exists');
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its bed practice to set session for the fill up data again. I will give you one way i hope it will help for you. i am not sure what is the structure of the coding. I think you have same problem which i face in past one of my cakephp project.

First of all assume we have a one controller lets say users controller and we have a one function like index then we create one view file for that. you can write following code there instead of your code

```
// Check Existing User
if ((int) $this->User->checkIfUserExist($this->request->data['User']['username']) > 0) {
   $this->set("message","Username Exists");
   $this->set("filled_data",$this->request->data)
}
```

Then at view file you can write this code

```
<?php
if(isset($message) && $message!=""){?>
     <span class="sessionflash"><?php echo $message; ?></span>
<?php }
?>
```

Give it style sheet to sessionflash which you want to give.

then in all text box you can write following code for example i am writing code for the first name text box

```
<input type="text" name="data[User][v_first_name]" id="v_first_name" value="<?php if(isset($filled_data) && isset($filled_data["User"]["v_first_name"])){echo $filled_data["User"]["v_first_name"]; } ?>">
```

So this is my logic which i use when i got the same problem. this example is helpful if you are not redirecting to another page and you are redirecting to same page when you have submitted this data.

sorry if i understand wrong about your requirement. if it is helpful i will be happy :)